# Python: Loop through JSON File

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm not sure how to loop through this particular structure where the top level keys A1 and B6 are random.

I want to be able to output name, x, y and yr

```
{
    "A1": {
        "msgs": ["Something there"],
        "name": "Mary White",
        "x": 132,
        "y": 73,
        "yr": 1978
    },
    "B6": {
        "msgs": ["Something here"],
        "name": "Joe Bloggs",
        "x": 132,
        "y": 73,
        "yr": 2016
    },
...
```

Using the following to load my JSON

```
import json

with open('items.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

Comment: @ZdaR no, you'd need to loop through `.items()`.

Comment: Where does json_ come into play? Updated question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Iterate through `.values()`:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    for v in data.values():
        print(v['x'], v['y'], v['yr'])
```

Comment: That only prints out the first one

Comment: @pee2pee Works fine for me. Check your json file. And try to `print(data)`.